# revtex incompatible with dblfloatfix?

Tags: floats, incompatibility, revtex

This minimal example makes my latex/pdflatex from MiKTeX (or TeX Live of a colleague) crash:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\begin{figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It writes out several 100 MB of log files until I force quit it. Why is this? Not using `dblfloatfix`, or using a different document class solves the problem, but not my use case.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question. I'm afraid that `dblfloatfix` is simply incompatible with `revtex4-1` because the class redefines very thoroughly the `figure` environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: they are not compatible. REVTeX includes a *lot* of code, fixes for things, modifications, *etc.* It's therefore quite 'picky' about what it will and won't work with. I'm afraid you almost certainly just have to 'get on' with this.