# revtex incompatible with stfloats?

Tags: floats, incompatibility, revtex

Very similar to this one:
[revtex incompatible with dblfloatfix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114499/revtex-incompatible-with-dblfloatfix)

Is revtex known to be incompatible with stfloats? In this MWE, the second figure is just gone (with a "Float cannot be placed" warning):

```
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure*}[t]
    \caption{I'm here in both cases!}
  \end{figure*}
  \lipsum[1-5]
  \begin{figure*}[b]
    \caption{I'm gone with revtex!}
  \end{figure*}
  \lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Using article instead works, and removing stfloats makes the figure appear (but on top of the third page, instead of bottom of second).