# Two-columns wide figure at the bottom of a page with Revtex

Tags: floats, positioning, two-column, revtex

The problem is simple: how to place a two-columns wide figure at the *bottom* of a page with the revtex document class? For those unfamiliar with revtex, it is a two-column style guide used by a number of physics journals.

I did extensive searching, only to find that many people face this problem (for example [Putting two-column wide figure in Revtex4-1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160730/putting-two-column-long-figure-in-revtex4-1)).

For a non-revtex document the usual solution is using the stfloats or the dblfloatfix package. Revtex is however incompatible with both packages ([revtex incompatible with stfloats?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149825/revtex-incompatible-with-stfloats) and [revtex incompatible with dblfloatfix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114499/revtex-incompatible-with-dblfloatfix)).

The revtex manual is also of no help with this problem.

I have been able to place a float at the position where I define it by wrapping it in the widetext environment, but this does improve readability.

A possible solution may be to use boxes in some way, but after some searching and trials I have not got this working.

The problem with the top placement is two-fold:
- multiple two-column images clutter up at the top of a page
- the text referring to the image(s) is lagging behind, forcing the reader to look at subsequent page(s) for the image.

So, anyone willing to pick up the challenge of solving this problem? A problem lasting for too long, for too many people.

Edit. A minimal working example as requested:

```
\documentclass[reprint, pre]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
%I want the figure at the bottom of the first page and 
%not on the top of the next page as it does now
\begin{figure*}[b]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{someImage.pdf}
    \caption{Some caption here.}
    \label{f:someImage}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make an example and provide a tabular inside a table environement, which you whish to set to a certain place.

Comment: If you need to place the picture, tabular, whatever on the bottom of the first page, then just don't use a float environment. Or would you like to know, how to place it on the bottom of a certain page, but not the first one of the document?

Comment: Then it will be placed at the position where I define it and not at the bottom. In addition, I would manually resolve white-space above and below the image, the caption, labeling, etc. But most importantly, journal editors will not like/accept this. Any change they make to the document changes the position of the image again and would require manual fixes.

Comment: From [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat), apparently `There is no bottom area for page-wide floats in two-column mode`. Because who would ever want that, right?