# How to not place a `figure*` at next page

Tags: floats, revtex

In writing a paper in the `revtex4-1` class. I have several wide pictures that I include with the `figure*` environment. On the last page there is already a figure on top that was included with the usual `figure` environment. I want another `figure*` to be placed at bottom of the same page. This seems impossible since `figure*` is always placed on the next page.
My problem is that the bibliography, that is included with `\bibliography{my_bib}` at the end of the file, now already starts before the last wide figure is placed.
I tried already several positioning commands, but the `float` package doesn't seems to work with `figure*`. Also a `\printfigures` command before including the bibliography didn't change anything.

EDIT:
I also tried hacks like `\onecolumngrid` and `\twocolumngrid` or the `widepage` environement. 
I could force the bibliography to appear after the last picture with the `\FloatBarrier` command provided by the `placeins` package. But this now just leaves a blank space at the position where the bibliography appeared before, instead of placing the picture there.

Comment: this is a duplicate: [Two-columns wide figure at the bottom of a page with Revtex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180262/579); unfortunately, it doesn't have an answer.  an answer to this other question provides a hack that could work for you: [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107270/579).

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Ha great, thanks already. Sorry for the duplicate, couldn't find the other discussion. So apparently "There is no bottom float area for double-column floats" is the not so nice answer. Thanks as well for the other link. I already wanted to ask, if there's a minipage hack. This trick however worked in the sense, that the picture is now indeed placed at the bottom, of the desired page, but half of it happily overwritten by the rest of text. Will see if I can somehow change that.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Either I didn't entirely get it, or the trick just didn't change anything. Still, thanks however.

Comment: overwritten ... that is the initial condition, and is actually a good start.  once you have the picture where you want it (at the bottom of a left-hand column), examine the right-hand column for a nice paragraph break in the non-overprinted area.  (let's hope there *is* one.)  measure (number of lines = N) equivalent that the picture requires.  then, in that paragraph gap, insert the instruction `\enlargethispage{-N\baselinekip}` with a blank line preceding and following it.  assuming that `revtex` is based on a `twocolumn` format, that should move what's overprinting onto the next page.

Answer (score 2):

Evidently `revtex4-1` doesn't allow floats on the bottom of pages, at least it sets `\bottomnumber` to 0 and `\bottomfraction` to .09.  If you don't mind incurring the wrath of the `revtex4-1` gods, this can be corrected.

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{mwe}

\def\bottomfraction{0.5}
\def\bottomnumber{1}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[b]
\includegraphics{example-image}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer, I tried it. But the behaviour unfortunately didn't change.

Comment: Without an MWE, we can only guess.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but it seems to be a rather special case. And I can't upload everything, since it's unpublished results. Still thanks for your effort.

Comment: A Minimal Working Example need not contain a single word of the original document.  You can get images and text (lipsum) from the mwe package.  You can use \rule to take up space, or use \setcounter{page}{99} to skip to the page giving you trouble.  All you need to do is reproduce the problem.